# Getting null body on saving card in vault of paypal

Tags: android, rest, paypal, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to Save a card in vault of paypal using Rest api

I am convert Curl to Kotlin code

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-cards/ \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-d '{
  "number": "4417119669820331",
  "type": "visa",
  "expire_month": "11",
  "expire_year": "2015",
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Shopper",
  "billing_address": {
    "line1": "52 N Main St.",
    "city": "Johnstown",
    "country_code": "US",
    "postal_code": "43210",
    "state": "OH",
    "phone": "408-334-8890"
  }
}'
```

here is the code i used

```
  @POST(AppConstants.SAVE_CARD)
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    fun saveCard(
            @Header("Authorization") token: String,
            @Body creditCard: CreditCard
    ): Call<CreditCardResponse>
```

but in response i am getting a null body and there is no error body in it.
anyone can detect whats the problem?

Comment: Could you please add the class `CreditCard`, what's in `AppConatants.SAVE_CARD` and are you correctly sending the token? Can you share that part of the code too?

Comment: AppConstants.SAVE_CARD contaions url for save card `/v1/vault/credit-cards/` , how can i add Authorization as Bearer type? i think this was the problem, i am simply sending the token as string

Comment: That's correct, but it must contain the `Bearer` part like in the curl request. Something like `saveCard("Bearer $token", ...)`. Is this what you're doing?